# Create CSS grid without div containers

Tags: html, css, grid

Hello stackoverflowers,

I'm having this piece of html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block row1 column1"></div>
    <div class="block row1 column2"></div>
    <div class="block row1 column3"></div>
    <div class="block row2 column1"></div>
    <div class="block row2 column2"></div>
    <div class="block row2 column3"></div>
    <div class="block row3 column1"></div>
    <div class="block row3 column2"></div>
    <div class="block row3 column3"></div>
</div>
```

How can I create a 3x3 grid from the divs with css without changing the html?

Kind regards, Dennis

Edit: Does someone know how to keep the blocks as a square and centered. For example the container is 700px x 700px and the blocks are 100px x 100px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
.block {
    float:left;
    width:33.3%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
}
```

The `float` lets the divs be by each others side, the width is 1/3.

**EDIT:**

If you want the blocks to be rectangular, you need to set the width AND the height.

Lets go with your example:

```
.container {
    width:700px
}
.block {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
}
```

Now, there will be 7 blocks in a row, as the blocks are 100px wide, and the container is 700px wide. if you want them to be 3 per row, you can add this CSS:

```
.block:nth-child(4n+4) {
    clear:left;
}
```

Or:

```
.column1 {
    clear:left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Extended the the question: Do you know how to keep the blocks as a square and centered. For example the container is 700px x 700px and the blocks are 100px x 100px.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the both questions -

```
<h1>3x3 Grid</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="block row1 column1">1</div>
    <div class="block row1 column2">2</div>
    <div class="block row1 column3">3</div>
    <div class="block row2 column1">4</div>
    <div class="block row2 column2">5</div>
    <div class="block row2 column3">6</div>
    <div class="block row3 column1">7</div>
    <div class="block row3 column2">8</div>
    <div class="block row3 column3">9</div>
</div>

<h1>Centered box with 100px x 100px</h1>
<div class="container container2">
    <div class="block row1 column1">1</div>
    <div class="block row1 column2">2</div>
    <div class="block row1 column3">3</div>
    <div class="block row2 column1">4</div>
    <div class="block row2 column2">5</div>
    <div class="block row2 column3">6</div>
    <div class="block row3 column1">7</div>
    <div class="block row3 column2">8</div>
    <div class="block row3 column3">9</div>
</div>

.container *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
    width:700px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container:after{
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:"";
}
.block {
    float:left;
    width:33.3%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
}

.container2{
    text-align:center;
}
.container2 .block{
    float:none;
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I guess you got answer for both of your questions.